# Adding Sub Nodes to a List Of nodes

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, treeview

I understand my title was very vague I'm not sure how to sum it up.

I have a connection to a MySQL database that takes a column from the table I want to view in my treeView and adds the data in each row as a node, I want to add sub nodes to the nodes I add but the data will change depending on each node.

```
        string myConString = "Server=localHost;Database=fakekeeper;Uid=root;Pwd=**********;";
        string query = "SELECT OSP FROM OSP;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConString);
        MySqlDataReader reader;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        TreeNode tables = new TreeNode();

        treeView1.Nodes.Add(tables);

        while (reader.Read())
        {

            tables.Nodes.Add(reader["OSP"].ToString());
        }
        conn.Close();
```

The way it works in my database is each product has an OSP because an OSP can have many products but a product can only have one OSP, I want to make it so in my tree view when I double click the OSP it shows me all the Products associated with that OSP in the treeView as nodes I'm not sure if I can add them within my while loop or if I need to create another?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out by myself just by adding another while loop I managed to add to the nodes:

```
        string myConString = "Server=localHost;Database=fakekeeper;Uid=root;Pwd=**********;";
        string query = "SELECT OSP FROM OSP;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myConString);
        MySqlDataReader reader;
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        TreeNode tables = new TreeNode();

        treeView1.Nodes.Add(tables);

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            TreeNode alphaNode = new TreeNode(reader["OSP"].ToString());
            tables.Nodes.Add(alphaNode);
            MySqlConnection subNodeConn = new MySqlConnection(myConString);
            string subNodeQuery = string.Format("SELECT product FROM {0};", reader["OSP"].ToString());
            MySqlCommand subNodeCommand = new MySqlCommand(subNodeQuery, subNodeConn);
            MySqlDataReader subNodeReader;
            subNodeConn.Open();
            subNodeReader = subNodeCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while(subNodeReader.Read())
            {
                alphaNode.Nodes.Add(subNodeReader["Product"].ToString());
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
```

Please tell me if there is a more efficient way of doing this though?